# Properly setting VLCJ tonemapping

Tags: vlc, libvlc, vlcj, vlcj-javafx

I am currently trying to reproduce an HDR video with VLCJ but it does not seem to work. Tonemapping seems to be ignored as any value change results in no difference in video output. 
My current args are these:

```
String[] args = {"--tone-mapping=3", "--tone-mapping-param=0.5"};
mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(discovery, args);
```

This has no effect on the output.
Also, when playing video on the installed vlc, the color grading/tone mapping is correct and the video looks fine. It is only washed out in vlcj